# Two family members with same last and first names

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, applications

We are a family of four (me, my husband, 10-year-old daughter and 18-month-old son), applying for B1/B2 visas. I am the primary applicant. In tge DS 160 form, I am supposed to add my family members traveling with me under “Travel Companions information”.

The problem is that my husband and my son have the same first and last names. As the result, I have two persons with the same name traveling with me. Although I marked them as “son” and “spouse” I received a flag and can’t save the form.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81510/discussion-on-question-by-alla-reznik-two-family-members-with-same-last-and-firs).

Comment: I've marked this as "unclear what you're asking" because some potential ideas (e.g. Jr. and Sr.) have been suggested in the comments, but the question hasn't been updated to rule these in or out.